# URL from location.href missing searchParams

Tags: javascript, url, query-string, location-href

I'm trying to parse the query/search parameters of the current route

```
let url = new URL(location.href);
```

When I look at `url` the search parameters are in `href`. I expected them to be in `searchParams`, which is empty. Are my expectations off?

URL:

```
hash: "#/admin?ac=flags"
host: "localhost:8084"
hostname: "localhost"
href: "http://localhost:8084/#/admin?ac=flags"
origin: "http://localhost:8084"
password: ""
pathname: "/"
port: "8084"
protocol: "http:"
search: ""
searchParams: URLSearchParams { }
```

Comment: I think because the `?` is coming after the `#` in your URL it's not getting picked up in the searchParams. If you do `let url = new URL('http://localhost:8084/admin?ac=flags` the search is set to `?ac=flags` like I you'd expect.

Comment: thanks @Maria -- that was it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`href` contains the *whole* URL

The query string will appear in `searchParams` but your URL doesn't have a query string.

You have a fragment identifier (the section starting with `#`) which is the last component of the URL.

If you were to have a query string, you need a section starting with `?` *after* the path but **before** the fragment identifier.

Answer (score 0):

No, your expectations are right.
Indeed, the searchParams property returns an object URLSearchParams and it is not empty.

let urlparams = (new URL(location.href)).searchParams;

Now, urlparams holds the object and you can use get method:

urlparams.get("ac")

Comment: If you do the above with the href in the original post the get returns null.